# iOS NSURLConnection error -1002

Tags: ios, swift, networking, udp, gcdasyncsocket

I have an app that requires a to communicate with another device using `UDP`.
I am using the `GCDAsyncUDPSocket` framework.

I do not know the port that it will be required to send back over until I first receive on port 14550.

To get around this I implement 2 different sockets, a transmit socket and a receive socket.

First I initialise both sockets and open port 14550 on the receive socket.

```
func wifiConnect() {
    receiveSocket = GCDAsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
    transmitSocket = GCDAsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
    do {
        try receiveSocket!.bindToPort(14550)
        try transmitSocket!.enableBroadcast(true)
        try receiveSocket!.beginReceiving()
    } catch _ as NSError { print("Issue with setting up listener") }
}
```

Then I wait until data is received on that port and then I connect to the sender address for the transmit socket.

```
    func udpSocket(sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromAddress address: NSData, withFilterContext filterContext: AnyObject?) {
    if !udpConneced {
        do {
            try transmitSocket?.connectToAddress(address)
        } catch let error {
            NSLog("Error connecting to address. %@",String(error))
            return
        }
    }
    dataReceived(data)
}
```

Once connected `udpConnected` is set to true and a function is ran.

```
    func udpSocket(sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didConnectToAddress address: NSData) {
    udpConnected = true
    didConnect()
}
```

However, sometimes the entire app is crashing and giving this error

```
NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002
```

Which I understand to be an invalid URL, however I am not passing any urls myself to either socket.

What is causing this issue? I do know the IP of the connecting device so should I be using that to connect the transmit socket?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't include the answer in your question. You can post your own *answer* if you resolved your problem yourself. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Solved this. Turns out testflight was not reporting showing the full crash log. I managed to cause the crash myself and saw that it was nothing to do with NSURL or GCDASYNC. It was caused by a variable being nil whilst being called in a rare situation.**